# Large numerical discrepancy in the scipy package(see the screenshots for the reproducibility)

Tags: numpy, debugging, scipy

Consider the following integral

```
int dv from -1 to 1  ( int du from -1 to v  ( 1/sqrt(1-u^2)/sqrt(v-u) ))
```

where the exact result was `4/sqrt(2)=5.65685`. The wolframalpha was able to provide the exact result, while in scipy

```
def integrand02(u, v): 
    return (1/np.sqrt(v-u))/np.sqrt(1-u**2);
def integral_03(v):
    return integrate.quad(integrand02, -1, v , args=(v,))[0];
integrate.quad(integral_03, -1,1)

(5.158207687859731, 4.814388887552923e-10)
```

and

```
def integrand02(u, v): 
    return (1/np.sqrt(v-u))/np.sqrt(1-u**2);

integrate.dblquad(integrand02, -1,1,-1, lambda v:v)

(5.158207687859731, 8.408088447708906e-08)
```

consistently provided a value that's smaller than 5.6 by almost 10%.

[image: Just in case if you could not reproduce the result.]

This did not appear to be an issue of the interface

[image]

Is there a bug and how to fix it?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Which python version did you used?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate: which version of SciPy and Python are *you* using, and which platform/OS?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The latest anaconda distribution windows 11 python 3.9.12.(package in the screen shot)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I put the screenshots of the jupyter note book and the python terminal in the post. It's a very legit question and not hallucination .

Comment: I have an installation of SciPy 1.7.1 where I can reproduce the result of your first example.  In SciPy 1.9.0, there was a significant change made to the Fortran code used by `quad` that fixed a problem that could occur with nested integrals; see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/15997.  If you can, update to version 1.9.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser But the dblquad also produced the same results, would that be affected as well? I'm asking this because this was an initial post of something that might have gone very wrong in the numerical calculation, where scipy seemed to have provided "consistently wrong results", to a power law order dependence. This was only an initial post, where once the math exchange reproved and confirmed the analytic results, there might need major debug to the scipy integral package.

Comment: The issue was Fortan compiler dependent; see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6882